# change css by reading a value from database in php

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, database

I am trying to change my css dynamically. My css value should come from a database. I have a `goals` table in my database named `order` and it contains `id` and `goal_1`.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','order');
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM `goals`";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $width = $row["goal_1"]; `// storing value in a variable from db.`
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>project-1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.php">
</head>
    <body class="container">
        <div>
            <h4>Goal_1</h4>
            <h5><?php echo $width ?></h5> // this value is supposed to came from db.
            <hr align="left" class="goal goal_1">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to make the width of tag `<hr>` dynamic. Suppose the value of `goal_1` came from db `2`. Now the width of my `<hr>` should become `2px`. For this purpose, I am using a `style.php` file.

```
// my css file
<?php 
    header('Content-Type: text/css');
?>
.container {
    width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div{
    float: left;
    width: 330px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.goal{
    height:15px;
    background-color:#32CD32;
}
.goal_1{
    width: <?php $width ?>px; `// i am trying to do this to take the value form my db. but its not working`
}
h4{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
h5{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 35px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing

```
.goal_1{
    width: <?php $width ?>px;
}
```

to

```
.goal_1{
    width: <?php echo $width; ?>px;
}
```

and also possibly

```
<h5><?php echo $width ?></h5>
```

to

```
<h5><?php echo $width; ?></h5>/* trailing semi-colon */
```

--

A possible work-around that does not mean putting the db code inside `style.php` would be to use a session variable which can be populated in `index.php` and made available within `style.php`

So, for example:

```
<?php
    /* index.php */
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['style']=(object)array(
        'h1'    =>  (object)array('color'=>'red','font-size'=>'1.25rem'),
        'hr'    =>  (object)array('width'=>'500px'),
    );
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dynamic styles</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.php' />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Dynamic style</h1>
        <hr />
    </body>
</html>

<?php
    /* style.php */
    session_start();
    if( !empty( $_SESSION['style'] ) ){

        $obj=$_SESSION['style'];

        $h1=$obj->h1;
        $hr=$obj->hr;



    }

?>
h1{
    color:<?php echo $h1->color; ?>;
    font-size:<?php echo $h1->{'font-size'}; ?>
}
hr{
    width:<?php echo $hr->width;?>;
}
```

etc

Comment: maybe i should also import my db in style.php file ?

Comment: and if you were to look at the source of `style.php` in the browser does it look correct?

Comment: tried this for myself - should have remembered it wouldn't work like this. Putting the db code in the `style.php` should work